# API Testing with BDD

Tags: frameworks

We are using Cucumber in Java with Maven. I am looking to build the framework for Rest Api's with BDD. Can you please help me and share any existing framework for API testing

Comment: nobody will share their framework unless you don't want to try to create a framework on your own...
Please try something, make an effort.. help may be provided

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you take a look at [Ginkgo4j](http://paulcwarren.github.io/ginkgo4j/).  This is a Java BDD framework based on Ruby's RSpec.  Can be combined with library's like RestAssured to test REST APIs.